# Using the Model to Search Specific Field

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I'm trying to write a method in the model that will allow me to return posts who have a specific field value that is greater than 0.

So I have posts that have fields that are essentially tags. Basically I post has four fields, hiphop, electro, house and pop. Each field has a value between 0 and 10.

I'm trying to make it so if someone clicks on a button the the view that says "Hip Hop" it will return all posts that have a hiphop field value that is greater than 0.

I know this is wrong but I'm thinking something like this

```
  def self.tagSearch(query)
    where("#{query} > 0")
  end
```

and in my controller I would have something like this

```
  def index
    if params[:search]
      @songs = Song.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
    elsif params[:tag]
      @songs = Songs.tagSearch(params[:tag]).order("created_at DESC")
    else
      @songs = Song.all
    end
  end
```

And I'm not sure about the view but maybe a button that passes the tag value parameter. The thing is I just want it to be a button, I don't need them to input anything.

I hope this isn't too confusing.

Thank you!

Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on RaVen post:

1) Use ruby naming conventions `tagSearch` should be `tag_search`; methods are snake case (lower case with underscores).

2) `where("#{query} > 0")` is exposing you to SQL injection attacks - recommended to install the brakeman gem which can expose security issues like this:

- http://brakemanscanner.org/docs/warning_types/sql_injection/
- http://brakemanscanner.org/docs/

3) You can simplify your code by chaining scopes, scopes that return nil will not effect the query

```
class Song
  scope :search, -> (query) do 
    where("name LIKE ?", "#{query}%") if query.present?
  end

  scope :tag_search, -> (tag) do 
    where(tag > 0) if tag.present?
  end

  scope :ordered, -> do 
    order(created_at: :desc)
  end
end

class SongsController
  def index
    @songs = Song.search(params[:search])
               .tag_search(params[:tag])
               .ordered
  end
end
```

4) Making queries based on a user specified column and avoiding sql injection:

This is one way to do it, there are probably other better ones available, like using the models `arel_table`, anyhow this one is pretty straight forward

```
  scope :tag_search, -> (tag) do 
    where("#{self.white_list(tag)} > 0") if tag.present?
  end

  def self.white_list(column_name)
    # if the specified column_name matches a model attribute then return that attribute
    # otherwise return nil which will cause a sql error
    # but it won't let arbitrary sql execution
    self.attribute_names.detect { |attribute| attribute == column_name }
  end
```

Comment: AWESOME! Thank you so much house9. I learnt a lot from this post!

Answer (score 2):

Rails support "scopes" which return an `ActiveRecord::Relation` which means you can chain them together.

```
class Song
  scope :tag_search, -> (something) { where(something > 0) }
  scope :ordered, -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
end

class SongsController
  def index
    if params[:search]
      @songs = Song.search(params[:search]).ordered
    elsif params[:tag]
      @songs = Songs.tag_search(params[:tag]).ordered
    else
      @songs = Song.all
    end
  end
end
```

I would overthink the design of this.

Plus your `tagSearch` function is really dangerous. **SQL INJECTION!**

Comment: Thanks RaVeN - very helpful!